# Issue loading values from a text file into an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to load an array, and print the number if items in the array (array_num) and also the value in the 0 place in the array. MY code is not working very well, and I am wondering why. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The input file is:

```css
     -1.000000
      0.250000
     -1.333333
      0.484375
      1.958333
      3.119792
      4.000000
      4.630208
      5.041667
      5.265625
      5.333333
      5.276042
      5.125000
      4.911458
      4.666667
      4.421875
      4.208333
      4.057292
      4.000000
      4.067708
      4.291667
      4.703125
      5.333333
      6.213542
      7.375000
      8.848958
     10.666667
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//start of main code
int main(void)
{
    //declare variables
    float x1, h;
    int i, array_num;
    float diff_arr[50];

    FILE*indiff;
    indiff = fopen("indiff.txt","r");

    if (indiff == NULL)
        printf("Error Opening File...\n");
    else{
        fscanf(indiff, "%f", &x1);
        fscanf(indiff, "%f", &h);

        //start while loop
        while ((fscanf(indiff, "%f\n", &diff_arr[i])) == 1)
        {
            //fscanf(indiff, "%f\n",&diff_arr[load_array]);
            array_num++;
        }
        /*for (load_array=0;load_array<=50;load_array++)
        {
            fscanf(indiff, "%f\n",&diff_arr[load_array]);
            array_num++;
        */}
        printf("%f\n",diff_arr[0]);
        printf("%i\n",array_num);



    }
```

Comment: What's in the input file?

Comment: `i` is never initialized and advaced.

Comment: Would you mind providing a sample of the input file @python_pirate

Comment: Also what do you mean by "not working well"

Comment: @chbchb55 I updated it, and I mean it is printing 10.666667 for the first position in the array instead of -1.333333

Comment: @AlexLop. , isn't it initialized in the op of the code?

Comment: @python_pirate No, `int i;` is only a declaration. But what value does it contain? It is undefined! Fix it to `int i = 0;` I also believe you would like to advance it at some point by `i++;`, otherwise it will always be 0.

Comment: @python_pirate It shows the first element `-1.3333` because the real first two elements you read separately and stored in `x1` and `h`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code neither `i` nor `array_num` are never initialized!

`int i, array_num;` is only a declaration! Fix it to `int i=0, array_num=0;`

I believe you would also like to advance `i` at some point, otherwise it will always be 0. Probably here:

```
while ((fscanf(indiff, "%f\n", &diff_arr[i++])) == 1)
```